# Python requests to catch post response

Tags: python, post, web-crawler, python-requests

I want to catch the response from POST by Python package 'requests'. Here is the website: [A trip planner could response train route](https://tp.transportnsw.info/nsw/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2). From the safari element inspection, I got where the form sent to and form data, so I code python as below:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://tp.transportnsw.info/nsw/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2', data = {'name_destination': 'Chatswood Station, Chatswood', 'name_origin': 'Central Station, Sydney'})
```

Form data is to fill my origin station and destination station, trying to get the best train route. But after I post my form, the return value r is still the previous page. I can't get the response.

Can anyone tell me why.

Thank you.

Comment: You're sure the page returned isn't populated with the data you need? It could be that the server generates the HTML code and just populates it with the data.

Comment: I am sure about it. I check the generated HTML code and it isn't what i want.

Comment: There are actually a lot of requests going on behind the scenes, look under the xhr tab in chrom tools and you will see.